# How to do different drawings in different methods using paintComponent?

Tags: java, swing

I have 2 classes, one which extends a panel and other which extends a frame.

First class, the panel(used for drawings):

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class GraficPne extends JPanel{


public int dim1 = 0, dim2 = 0;
public JLabel lblSem1GraficPne, lblSem2GraficPne;

public GraficPne(){
    super();
    this.setLayout(null);
    this.setupComponents();

}


public void setupComponents(){

    lblSem1GraficPne = new JLabel("Sem I");
    lblSem2GraficPne = new JLabel("Sem II");

    lblSem1GraficPne.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    lblSem2GraficPne.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 12));

    this.add(lblSem1GraficPne);
    this.add(lblSem2GraficPne);
}

public void layComponents(int firstConv, int secondConv){

    lblSem1GraficPne.setBounds(20, getHeight() - firstConv - 20, 100, 20);
    lblSem2GraficPne.setBounds(100, getHeight() - secondConv - 20, 100, 20);

}



public void paint(Graphics g){

    super.paint(g);

    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth()-1, getHeight()-1);

    this.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillRect(20, getHeight()-dim1, 40, dim1);

    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.fillRect(100, getHeight()-dim2, 40, dim2);

    }



public void setData(int dim1, int dim2){

    this.dim1 = dim1;
    this.dim2 = dim2;

}

}
```

Second class, the frame, used to add the panel on it:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class GraficFrm extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

private JButton btnApply;
private JLabel lblSem1, lblSem2;
private JTextField txtSem1, txtSem2;
private GraficPne ob; //the object from first class
private int firstConv = 0, secondConv = 0; 


public GraficFrm() {

    super("Grafic soft");
    initSettings();
    setupComponents();
}



private void initSettings() {

    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setLayout(null);
    this.setSize(400, 450);
    this.setLocation(100, 100);
    this.setResizable(false);

}


private void setupComponents() {


    ob = new GraficPne();
    lblSem1 = new JLabel("Sem I");
    txtSem1 = new JTextField();
    lblSem2 = new JLabel("Sem II");
    txtSem2 = new JTextField();
    btnApply = new JButton("Apply");

    ob.setBounds(30, 50, 340, 200);
    lblSem1.setBounds(30, 280, 100, 20);
    txtSem1.setBounds(150, 280, 220, 20);
    lblSem2.setBounds(30, 330, 100, 20);
    txtSem2.setBounds(150, 330, 220, 20);
    btnApply.setBounds(170, 380, 80, 30);

    this.add(lblSem1);
    this.add(ob);
    this.add(txtSem1);
    this.add(lblSem2);
    this.add(txtSem2);
    this.add(btnApply);

    btnApply.addActionListener(this);

}


public void getConvertedValues(){

    String txtField1 = txtSem1.getText();
    firstConv = Integer.parseInt(txtField1);
    String txtField2 = txtSem2.getText();
    secondConv = Integer.parseInt(txtField2);

}


public void getHighValues(){

    if((firstConv > 100) || (secondConv > 100)) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Only values < 100 are allowed");

        firstConv = 0;
        secondConv = 0;
        txtSem1.setText("");
        txtSem2.setText("");
        ob.removeAll();
        ob.repaint();
    }

}



public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


    if(e.getSource().equals(btnApply)){

        try{

        new GraficFrm();
        getConvertedValues();
        getHighValues();
        ob.setData(firstConv, secondConv);
        ob.layComponents(firstConv,secondConv);
        ob.repaint();

        }catch(NumberFormatException ex1){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Only natural numbers are allowed");
        }

    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    GraficFrm frm = new GraficFrm();
    frm.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

All I want to do is to create a new method called getNegativeValues(), which would be called by pressing the Apply button, and this method to be executed when firstConv or secondConv would be < than 0. The block of my method, getNegativeValues(), i want to keep only the green background of the panel, as it is in paint(Graphics g), but to draw a center horizontal line(g.drawLine(0, getHeight()/2, getWidth(), getHeight()/2);). Then, when i execute the program and i type, let's say the value 55 for the first textfield and -40 for the second one, to draw 55 over my center horizontal line and -40 under my center horizontal line, and the 0 point would be on this center horizontal line.

LE:
@nIcE cOw i'll make a short recap: So, first, when i execute my app, i just want to appear my green panel and those 2 labels which have 2 textfields, as in my example(try to follow my example, please)(all good, i already did this, so this part is done). After, when i complete those 2 textfields let's say with 2 positive values, and then when i press the Apply button to happen exactly like in my example(without any center vertical line)(so already did this, also). All good, but my problem is: If complete one of those 2 textfields with a negative value and other with a positive one, and after i press the Apply button, i want that my application to recognize that there is a negative value typped in one of my textfields, thus to draw me on my green panel a center horizontal line(after i press the Apply button) and to draw those 2 rectangles exactly as you did in your first picture uploaded. Please help me, as i said i'll help you to understand what i want to do, and also i want to say i really appreciate your effort and i'm sorry (again) if i was confused(again).

Comment: Why not try the solution you've described. When you run into an issue, come back to us.

Comment: You seem to have a good description of what you want to do, what is the issue you're having with it?

Comment: The problem is i don't know how to draw, because if i put the horizontal line in class of my panel this would be displayed everytime i execute my application, and what i want to do is to execute only when i press Apply button, in a different method.

Comment: `public class GraficPne extends JPanel{ .. public void paint(Graphics g){

    super.paint(g);` is definitely wrong.  For `JPanel`, `@Override paintComponent(Graphics)` 2) Use layouts in the panel & frame.  3) Don't extend frame, just use an instance. 4) One blank line of white space is always enough.

Comment: I understood that paint() is for Canvas and paintComponent() for JPanel, but this does not solve my problem yet. What if i use layout on null and i extend frame instead of using an instance of jpanel? Can you give me a crisp answer? Ps: I've edited paintComponent(Graphics g) instead of paint(Graphics g).

Comment: Tip:  Add @PersonName to notify them of a new comment.  None of the points I made were intended to solve the problem, they were just notes about coding style & use of the API.  If they were intended to address your question (which I'm still not sure what is) they'd be an answer instead of a comment.  I recommend you follow the advice of Chris.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess, what you looking for is a method as presented below, that might can calculate, the starting point of Rectangles that you are trying to draw on the `JPanel`. Here `pos` is Positive Value and `neg` is Negative Value:

```
public void setValues(int above, int below)
{
    midPoint = getHeight() / 2;
    heightAbove = Math.abs(above);
    heightBelow = Math.abs(below);
    /*
     * If both are negative values, 
     * we need a Mid-Point in this case.
     */
    if (above < 0 && below < 0)
    {
        rectAbove = midPoint;
        diff = 120;
        rectBelow = midPoint;
        flag = true;
    }
    else if (above >= 0 && below >= 0)
    {
        rectAbove = getHeight() - heightAbove;
        diff = 120;
        rectBelow = getHeight() - heightBelow;
        flag = false;
    }
    else if (above < 0 && below >= 0)
    {
        rectAbove = midPoint;
        diff = 40;
        rectBelow = midPoint - heightBelow;
        flag = true;
    }
    else if (above >= 0 && below < 0)
    {
        rectAbove = midPoint - heightAbove;
        diff = 40;
        rectBelow = midPoint;
        flag = true;
    }       

    repaint();
}
```

Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class PaintingRectangles
{
    private JTextField aboveField;
    private JTextField belowField;
    private JButton applyButton;
    private MyCanvas canvas;

    private void displayGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Painting Rectangles Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 5));

        JPanel rightPanel = new JPanel();
        rightPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1, 5, 5));
        aboveField = new JTextField(10);
        belowField = new JTextField(10);
        applyButton = new JButton("Apply");
        applyButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {
                int above = 0;              
                int below = 0;
                try
                {
                    above = Integer.parseInt(aboveField.getText());
                    below = Integer.parseInt(belowField.getText());
                }
                catch(NumberFormatException nfe)
                {
                    aboveField.setText("0");
                    belowField.setText("0");
                    above = 0;
                    below = 0;
                    nfe.printStackTrace();
                }

                canvas.setValues(above, below);
            }
        });

        rightPanel.add(aboveField);
        rightPanel.add(belowField);
        rightPanel.add(applyButton);

        canvas = new MyCanvas();
        contentPane.add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        contentPane.add(rightPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_END);

        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new PaintingRectangles().displayGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}

class MyCanvas extends JPanel
{   
    private int midPoint = getHeight() / 2;
    private int rectAbove = getHeight() / 2;
    private int rectBelow = getHeight() / 2;    
    private int width = 40;
    private int heightAbove = 0;
    private int heightBelow = 0;
    private int diff = 0;
    private boolean flag = false;

    public MyCanvas()
    {
        setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    }

    public void setValues(int above, int below)
    {
        midPoint = getHeight() / 2;
        heightAbove = Math.abs(above);
        heightBelow = Math.abs(below);
        /*
         * If both are negative values, 
         * we need a Mid-Point in this case.
         */
        if (above < 0 && below < 0)
        {
            rectAbove = midPoint;
            diff = 120;
            rectBelow = midPoint;
            flag = true;
        }
        else if (above >= 0 && below >= 0)
        {
            rectAbove = getHeight() - heightAbove;
            diff = 120;
            rectBelow = getHeight() - heightBelow;
            flag = false;
        }
        else if (above < 0 && below >= 0)
        {
            rectAbove = midPoint;
            diff = 40;
            rectBelow = midPoint - heightBelow;
            flag = true;
        }
        else if (above >= 0 && below < 0)
        {
            rectAbove = midPoint - heightAbove;
            diff = 40;
            rectBelow = midPoint;
            flag = true;
        }       

        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize()
    {
        return (new Dimension(400, 400));
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {       
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        if (flag)
            g.drawLine(0, getHeight() / 2, getWidth(), getHeight() / 2);
        makeRectangles(g);
    }

    private void makeRectangles(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(40, rectAbove, width, heightAbove);

        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillRect(diff, rectBelow, width, heightBelow);

        g.dispose();
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

[image: RECTANGLES]
[image: RECTANGLES!]
[image: RECTANGLES2]
[image: RECTANGLES3]

Comment: +1 for [sscce](http://sscce.org/); minor nit: `Integer.parseInt` throws `java.lang.NumberFormatException` for empty string.

Comment: welcome in the ZOO, trashgod is right, interesting catch

Comment: I wanted to say that the horizontal center line would be active only if one of those 2 textfields detected a negative values(the Apply button would do this).. otherwise, if the values are > 0 to start exactly as it is in my above example. I hope you'll be able to help me now. Thanks anyhow a lot, i'm sorry if i was a little bit confused.

Comment: @VladDumitrache : A lil bit more clarification needed, what if both the values are positive, then where exactly you want the drawings to appear ? Just that much would be enough to think something about after I give my exam today.

Comment: @VladDumitrache : Please have a look at the latest edit too, in the code, to see if this is what is desired !!!

Comment: @nIcEcOw: I've edited my first post. Hope is clearly now.